# How to get the value of a field with ng-change

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I know how to react to user input in a textarea with ng-change in AngularJS. But how can I get the current input inside the Angular controller? I am missing something like `$(this).value();` in jQuery.

```
<script>
  angular.module('changeExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.evaluateChange = function() {
        console.log("How do I get the current content of the field?");
      };
    }]);
</script>

<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <textarea ng-change="evaluateChange()" id="ng-change-example1"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Use [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) instead

Answer (score 12):

ng-model

It'll store the value of an input, textarea, or select.

Your html should be like this:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <textarea ng-model="myValue" ng-change="evaluateChange()" id="ng-change-example1"></textarea>
</div>
```

Then in your controller you can reference that with `$scope.myValue`

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Thanks, that helps. But what if I have several textareas and I just want one function in my controller that reacts to changes in any of them. How would I reference that?

Comment: In this case I would probably put the evaulateChange() function in each ng-change of every textarea. Anytime one changes, the function will fire, and from there you can reference each individual ng-model within there

Comment: But how do I know from which textarea evaluateChange() was called? Is there any way to know?

Comment: you could pass in whatever the ng-model is into that evaluateChange()

Comment: so, evaluateChange(myValue), and whatever myValue is from is the one that changed

Comment: I had to pass "this" to the ng-change expression, so that in my directive I had one parameter, $scope, and then could access to $scope.myValue.

Answer (score 11):

You can make use of $event for getting value of current element. Something like this

```
<script>
  angular.module('changeExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.evaluateChange = function(obj,$event) {
        var currentElement = $event.target;
        console.log(currentElement.value);//this will give you value of current element
      };
    }]);
</script>

<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <textarea ng-change="evaluateChange(this)" id="ng-change-example1"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, but I don't get it: for me, it says "Cannot read property 'target' of undefined"

Comment: I think the $event variable is not passed on ng-change event, at least it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.myFunc = function(vals) {
        console.log(vals);
  $("#result").html(vals);
      };
    }]);
```

```css
body{
  background:#ffc10721;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" align="center">
  <p>Write something in the Textarea</p>
  <textarea ng-change="myFunc(myValue)" ng-model="myValue"></textarea>
  <br>Result :<p id="result"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain why this is the answer. Why does this work? What's the lesson to learn here?