# Trigger a button whenever a button is entered on a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This is a textarea element

```
<textarea id="textfield" paceholder="type anything here"></textarea>
```

This is a button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="button">Alert</button>
```

I can trigger the button above to alert the value of a textarea using jquery

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    var value = $('#textfield').val();
      alert(value);
  });
});
</script>
```

Is there a way I can use angular to trigger the button alert by default whenever a text or value enters into the textarea
I am trying to use something like this

```
$scope.$watch('textfield', function () {
//pop alert if textarea has a value
```

but somehow lost along the line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value of a field with ng-change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947808/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-field-with-ng-change)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built in [`ngKeyup`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup) directive of Angular

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
  <textarea ng-keyup="show($event)" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

Your js

```
angular.module("myapp",[])
.controller("myctrl", function($scope){
  $scope.show = function($event){
    alert($event.target.value);
  }
})
```

If you need to force a button click everytime text is entered alter your `show` function as follows

```
angular.module("myapp",[])
.controller("myctrl", function($scope){
  $scope.show = function($event){
    alert($event.target.value);
    document.querySelector(".btn").click();
  }
})
```

**note:** ngKeyup fires every time that key is released, if you need to listen for each character entered in the textaread use the ngChange event

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
  <textarea ng-change="show($event)" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: will this trigger a button with a particular ID

Comment: @JnG As it is now no. But inside the show function you can manually click the button with `document.querySelector(".btn").click();`

Comment: Please update your answer and show a demo if necessary. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ng-change will help:

```
<input type="textbox" ng-model="text" ng-change="change()"  />
```

In controller:

```
$scope.change = function() {
    alert($scope.text);
};
```

Comment: I want the button to be triggered not to watch the change