# Basic Comma to Dot Conversion

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a parameter dinamically generated based on an array

```
<input ng-change="vm.commaToDecimalConversion(this);" ng-value="templateParameter.value" ng-model="vm.parametersMap[templateParameter.dmsField]" />
```

I wanted to convert the input value from a comma to a dot when the user changes the input

```
 vm.commaToDecimalConversion = function(input) {
    console.log(input);
    var val = (input) ? input.value.toString().trim().replace(",",".") : null;
    console.log(val);
    console.log(input.value);
    return parseFloat(val);
}
```

My code gives errors on input.value.

How do I convert the value from the input dynamically?

Comment: Could you include the error that you are seeing in your question please?

Comment: try `.replace(/\,/gm, ".")`

Comment: Instead of `vm.commaToDecimalConversion = function(input)` try `vm.commaToDecimalConversion = function(input, $event){var inputValue = $event.target.value; }` See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30948203/1331040

Comment: function works for me

Comment: @WillTaylor `Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at OutgoingTemplatesCtrl.vm.commaToDecimalConversion`

Comment: Input is undefined, you are giving wrong param then.

Comment: `-> commaToDecimalConversion($('<input type="text" value="55,3">')[0]) <nl>
VM1947:2 <input type=​"text" value=​"55,3">​ <nl>
VM1947:4 55.3 <nl>
VM1947:5 55,3 <nl>
<- 55.3`